# Matlab: Elements stuck with Cell Type in Table

Tags: matlab

I have a table:

```
>> T2
T2 = 
    Eyetraction     Statues
    ____________    _______
    'Distractor'    0      
    'Distractor'    0      
    'Other'         0      
    'Other'         0      
    'Distractor'    0      
    'Target'        0      
    'Other'         0      
    'Distractor'    0      
    'Other'         0      
    'Target'        0
```

In the `doc table`, under section *Accessing Data in Table*, it suggests that I can use logical expressions to get a boolean array for indexing, like:

```
rows = T2.Eyetraction=='Other'
```

However, I got an error:

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Then I tried to use cell indexing, but still gets error:

```
>> T2.Eyetraction{:}=='Other'
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

My instinct told me to change the cell a string, but:

```
>> class( cellstr( T2.Eyetraction(2) ) ) 
ans =
cell
>> % -------- Cell '{}' indexing?
>> class( cellstr( T2.Eyetraction{2} ) )
ans =
cell
```

This shouldn't be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first column contains strings. Try this, `find(ismember(T2.Eyetraction,'Other'))`.

Comment: Thanks! the `ismember` (without `find()`) works, I'll use it for now.